PyQt6 Delegate class to show combo boxes in tableView cells, doesn't update model on selection. It has to be clicked again
I have revised this post in line with comments gratefully received.
I attach a simplified program to demonstrate the problem, and along the way to developing it I found the answer to my initial problem, which turned out to be a fault in the following line in the Delegate:setModelData method.
model.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(value), QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)

The value I needed should not have been a QVariant.
Another problem I found is that the initial contents of the tableView cells must exist in the comboBox list.  In my original code, where the TableView is populated from a pandas dataframe, the initial table values were pandas 'NaN' which did not exist in my list of categories populating the combo box.
Here is the simplified code:
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QTableView, QComboBox, QItemDelegate, QStyleOptionComboBox, QStyle, QVBoxLayout

class Delegate(QItemDelegate): #combo box delegate
    def __init__(self, choices):
        super(Delegate, self).__init__()        
        self.items = choices
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.editor = QComboBox(parent)
        self.editor.setFocus()
        self.editor.setEditable(True)
        self.editor.addItems(self.items)
        return self.editor
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        style = QApplication.style()
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        opt.text = str(value)
        opt.rect = option.rect
        style.drawComplexControl(QStyle.ComplexControl.CC_ComboBox, opt, painter)
        QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        num =   self.items.index(value)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(num)
        
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        
        
    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)






class CategoriesModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.categories = ['Invertebrate','Fish','Amphibian','Reptile','Bird','Mammal', 'N/A']
        self.uncategorised = [ ['Stickleback','N/A' ], ['Glow Worm','N/A' ], ['Python', 'N/A'], ['Black Widow', 'N/A'], ['Hedgehog', 'N/A'], ['Whale Shark','N/A' ] ]
        


    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.uncategorised)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            item =  self.uncategorised[index.row()][index.column()]
            return item
        else:
            return None

    def flags(self, index):
        return (QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            self.uncategorised[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        else:
            print(f'Bugger it! - role is {role} but should be {QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole} or {QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole}')
        return True
    
    def showModel(self):
        print(self.uncategorised)

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'form.ui'
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.6.1

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        #Dialog.resize(300, 300)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(parent=Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5,240, 295))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableView = QTableView(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from delegate import Delegate
from model import CategoriesModel

# Important:
# You need to run the following command to generate the ui_form.py file
#     pyqt6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py
from ui_form import Ui_Dialog

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = CategoriesModel()                 # Create a data model for Categories
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)         # Attach the model to the tableview in the dialog
        self.ui.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, Delegate(self.model.categories))
        self.ui.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.model.showModel)
#        for row in range( self.model.rowCount()):
#            self.ui.tableView.openPersistentEditor(self.model.index(row, 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Dialog()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Now, the issue remaining is that the model doesn't update when I select a category from the combo, but it waits until I click on another cell.  If the OK button is clicked it dumps the table contents to the terminal so you can see the problem for yourself.
Edit added 03052024:
I realise that it is the tableView that triggers the model updating,  not the combo box selection.  When a combo item is selected, the tableview does not see the underlying cell data change until the combo loses focus to some other part of the tableView or another combo box in another cell.
I need a signal from the combo for 'current Value Changed' to trigger a slot in the tableView, 'current cell value changed'

What is the data type of items in categoryList? Please provide a [mre], possibly without the need of BankData or at least with some dummy data that allows us to properly test your code. Also, try to avoid unnecessary description: the first 5 paragraphs of your post are irrelevant to the problem, so you could remove them. Finally, while not technically wrong, your usage of the ui class is a bit awkward (and the Ui_dialog subclassing is pointless); I suggest you to properly follow the official guidelines about using Designer.

Thanks for your comment, I will do as you suggest.  Apologies for the persiflage.

I attach the revised code that updates the underlying model as soon as a combo box item is selected:  The changes are:

No need to subclass QComboBox, so MyComboBox is unnecessary, however ...
Need to set the object name of each combo box in the Delegate class to something that relates to its position in the table - e.g. combo_0, combo_1 etc
In the Delegate class, must connect the activate signal of the combo to a custom slot in the model class.
In the Model class, create a method called customSlot, which works out which combo box is activated and calculates the modelIndex required to update the model.
In customSlot, call the model's setData method.

The overall need to name the combo's is a bit kludgey, it's just that the index returned from the combo when a selection is made, has nothing to do with modelIndex used to update the model.
Anyway, this was quite a journey.
    import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QTableView, QComboBox, QItemDelegate, QStyleOptionComboBox, QStyle, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Delegate(QItemDelegate): #combo box delegate

    count = 0
    def __init__(self, owner, model):
        super(Delegate, self).__init__()        
        self.items = ['N/A', 'Amphibian','Bird','Fish','Invertebrate','Mammal', 'Reptile']
        self.model = model
        self.owner = owner
        Delegate.setObjectName(self, 'Delegate')
        
    def createEditor(self, owner, option, index):
        self.editor = QComboBox(owner)
        self.editor.setFocus()
        self.editor.setEditable(True)
        self.editor.addItems(self.items)
        self.editor.setObjectName('combo_'+str(Delegate.count))
        self.editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.model.customSlot)
        Delegate.count += 1
        return self.editor
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        #value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        style = QApplication.style()
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        #opt.text = str(value)
        opt.rect = option.rect
        style.drawComplexControl(QStyle.ComplexControl.CC_ComboBox, opt, painter)
        QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        print(f'Delegate.setEditorData: self = {self.objectName()}, owner = {self.owner.objectName()}, editor name = {editor.objectName()}, index = {(index.row(), index.column())}')


        #value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        #self.setModelData(editor, self.owner, index)
        #num =   self.items.index(value)
        #editor.setCurrentIndex(num)
        
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        
        
    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

class CategoriesModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.uncategorised = [ ['Stickleback','N/A' ], ['Glow Worm','N/A' ], ['Python', 'N/A'], ['Black Widow', 'N/A'], ['Hedgehog', 'N/A'], ['Whale Shark','N/A' ] ]
        


    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.uncategorised)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            item =  self.uncategorised[index.row()][index.column()]
            return item
        else:
            return None

    def flags(self, index):
        return (QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            self.uncategorised[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        else:
            print(f'Bugger it! - role is {role} but should be {QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole} or {QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole}')
        return True
    
    def showModel(self):
        print(self.uncategorised)
        

    def customSlot(self, index):     # I need to know WHICH combo box has sent this message
        print(f'Delegate;customSlot: Bang!')
        sender = self.sender()
        name = sender.objectName()
        index = int(name[6:])
        
        if index < len(self.uncategorised):
            role =  QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
            print(f'CategoriesModel:customSlot: signal received from {name}')
            modelIndex = self.createIndex(index, 1)
            self.setData(modelIndex, sender.currentText(), role)
            print(f'CategoriesModel: Custom Slot goes bang for index = {modelIndex.row(), modelIndex.column()} and text = {sender.currentText()}!')
        else:
            print(f'Model goes tits-up for index = {index} and value = {value}!')

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'form.ui'
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.6.1

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        #Dialog.resize(300, 300)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(parent=Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5,240, 295))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableView = QTableView(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Cancel|QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))



# Important:
# You need to run the following command to generate the ui_form.py file
#     pyqt6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py
from ui_form import Ui_Dialog

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = CategoriesModel()                 # Create a data model for Categories
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)         # Attach the model to the tableview in the dialog
        self.ui.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, Delegate(self, self.model))
        self.ui.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.model.showModel)
        for row in range( self.model.rowCount()):
            self.ui.tableView.openPersistentEditor(self.model.index(row, 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Dialog()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

